# Sign in to WhatsApp account on old number without old SIM card

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, sim-card, data-transfer

I want to restore my phone to factory settings, which means WhatsApp will be deleted. I use my old number on WhatsApp, and I don't have the SIM card. If I downloaded WhatsApp again and tried to sign in with my old number, can I do that?

Example:

- Old no. 555-1234 - WhatsApp
- New no. 555-9876 - no WhatsApp

Can I use the old one once again?

Comment: Nope I can't anyway, it seems to send an SMS, and register the SIM not the device.

Answer (score 0):

The way WhatsApp authentication works is that it sends an SMS to the number for verification. This means that you won't be able to re-authenticate to that account without access to the phone number (as you have said in your comment)

A possible workaround is if you root your device, you can back up the WhatsApp data using something like [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) and then restore it on the fresh install. Depending on how their authentication keys work, you may trick the app into still using your old account.